# Add new line characters (\n) into CSV file?

Tags: c++, excel, csv, libreoffice

I have a CSV files whose data is taken from multiple other CSV files. I copied over the data from these files one column at a time and I want the file to be read one line at a time using the c++ method getLine().

Problem is that getLine returns the entire file as one line. I suspect the way I copied them and did not include a column with an end line character has lead to each row not having the character at the end.

Is there a way to add them in? I'm using Libre Office but I can also switch to excel.

Comment: "/n"? That's not a newline, that's a slash and the letter n. Also, if you're on Windows a newline is actually *two* character, the sequence carriage-return and newline (`"\r\n"`).

Comment: The getline() method can take another argument, the delimiting character. You can specify your own delimiting character (maybe a comma). Other than that, I think simplest would be to regenerate the CSV file again with the new line characters.

Comment: Get yourself a decent **text** editor. I'd recommend notepad++. It will be able to tell you what line endings you have and/or convert to a different type of line ending.

Comment: Sorry bout that, my keyboard doesn't have the other slash. Oh, an I am currently using Ubuntu and eclipse.

Comment: Off-topic: there are keyboards without backslashes? How do you write programs??

Comment: The backslash `\ ` is usually above the enter key.  If you really don't have a backslash, get a new keyboard and in the meantime do something like `const char NEWLINE = 0x0A;` and use that.

Comment: @Cory Nelson do you have a MAC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open it in Libre Office's word processor. Save it as whatever file type Libre saves documents. That should add the proper line endings. Then save it back as plain text.